# Wrap a React route render function in a HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, higher-order-components

I am using React-Router 4 to create some routes. (It uses the `PrivateRoute` component from the [official docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) but that's not relevant to this question.)

```
<HashRouter>    
    <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute exact path='/' component={Wrapper(Home)} />
        <Route exact path='/login' render={(props) => <Login authenticate={this.authenticate} {...props} />} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path='/clients' component={Wrapper(Clients)} />
    </Switch>
</HashRouter>
```

As you can see the `Home` and `Clients` components are wrapped in an [HOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html). For the moment this does nothing:

```
const Wrapper = (Page) => {
    return (props) => (
        <div className="page">
            <p>This should be on every page</p>
            <Page {...props} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

This works fine. What I can't figure out is how to wrap the `Login` route in the same HOC. I've tried

```
<Route exact path='/login' render={(props) => Wrapper(<Login authenticate={this.authenticate} {...props} />)} />
```

But this returns the error:

> Route.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try doing it like that:

```
<Route exact path='/login' render={(props) => Wrapper(Login)({...props, authenticate: this.authenticate})} />
```

Because now Wrapper HOC is returning a function, but the react element is expected. To get the react element we'll need to call this function with the needed props and that seems like a good place to add that extra prop `this.authenticate`.

Here's a quick snippet I made: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zestnq